# Return true and then break from a for loop

Tags: java

I'm new to java.
I have been trying to do something without success.
Basically What I want to do is to create a method that return true or false. The method gets some parameter, checks if a certain array is full, if not it pushes the parameters to the to the first cell that isn't empty, return true and NOT keep checking for the rest of the array.
If the array is full it just return false.
This is the code:

```
public boolean add( param1, param2, param3 ){
 for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
   if ( array[i] == null ){
     array[i] =  new SomeObject( param1, param2, param3 ); 
     return true;
     break;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

But I get error- "unreachable statement" for "break;".
Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you have a return statement, you don't need to `break` from the loop, since the return statement ends the execution of the method. Just remove the `break` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. So basically every time there is a return statement inside method, it ends the execution, even if the return is, for example, inside 3 nested loops?

Comment: @Avishay28 yes, `return` always returns out of the method.

Answer (score 2):

As some people insist on a function having a single point of return, the function can be reformulated as follows, matching the apparent expectation of the original question.

```
public boolean add( param1, param2, param3 ){
    boolean result = false;
    for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
        if ( array[i] == null ){
            array[i] =  new SomeObject( param1, param2, param3 ); 
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: A sound approach, though capitalizing `Result` is a jarring departure from convention.

Comment: Why making another variable? How it is better then the original code (without the break statement of course)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have de-capitalized it to make it more socialist.

Comment: @Avishay28 It is not 'better' in some objective sense; however it seemed to me that the original poster's intuition was somehow that the return statement does not immediately terminate the function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Because the moment the control encounters a return statement it just gets out of a method, switch or a loop etc. so any code written below the return statement will be just "unreachable." So its always advisable to place the return at the last of the block (of a method) unless required and it is also advisable not to write any code after the **return** statement in a single block lest you should get an error.